# Can I change class/stats between playthroughs in Mass Effect 1?

Tags: mass-effect

I was wondering if I start a new game and carry over my Shepard from my first playthrough, can I switch up stats and my class? This isn't moving from Mass Effect 1 to Mass Effect 2, strictly in Mass Effect 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot change your stats or class in a new game plus.  Your class and stats and gear remain from the prior playthrough.

Your followers' stats reset and can be allocated differently.